# jquery tooltip set timeout

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to show a tooltip which will disappear after 3 seconds time.

How should I modify my code? seems commented code will not work:

http://jsfiddle.net/sMJ2T/1/

HTML

```
<div id="mytooltip" title="the message"></div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $('#mytooltip').tooltip();

    $('#mytooltip').tooltip({
    open: function(e,o){
        $(o.tooltip).mouseover(function(e){
            $('#mytooltip').tooltip('close');
        });
        $(o.tooltip).mouseout(function(e){
        });         
    },
    close: function(e,o) {},
    show: { duration: 800 }
});

    $('#mytooltip').tooltip('open');//.delay(2000).tooltip('close');


});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#mytooltip').tooltip();

    $('#mytooltip').tooltip({
        open: function (e, o) {
            $(o.tooltip).mouseover(function (e) {
                $('#mytooltip').tooltip('close');
            });
            $(o.tooltip).mouseout(function (e) {});
        },
        close: function (e, o) {},
        show: {
            duration: 800
        }
    });

    $('#mytooltip').tooltip('open');
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#mytooltip').tooltip('close'); //close the tooltip
    }, 3000); //but invoke me after 3 secs
});
```

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/sMJ2T/2/)

Comment: @monjevin which function in particular?

Comment: in my code here: `$('#mytooltip').tooltip('open').delay(3000).tooltip('close');`

Comment: @monjevin I wish I knew for sure, but it might be related to the fact that the `.delay` function works on the animation queue only. Maybe by calling `.open()` doesn't really put anything in the animation queue and that's why is has no effect? Or it does, but it finishes too quickly and so the queue is empty?

Answer (score 0):

This would work perfectly fine with Bootstrap 4 Tooltips

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
    setInterval(function () {
         $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide'); 
    }, 3000);
});
```

The tooltips would appear and disappear automatically after 3 seconds.

I know this question is already 7 years old but might still help someone!