# js Tooltip with delayed mouseout without jQuery

Tags: javascript, delay, mouseout

I want to display a **tooltip** when hovering a div. It should also be displayed when the mouse is hovering the `tooltip-div`.

Adding an event listener does this job, but if both divs are not overlapping the *mouseout* calls when the mouse is between them and the tooltip disappears.

Now I want to add a delay for the mouseout which is cancelled when it gets a new mouseover, but I don't know how.

```js
document.getElementById("hoverElem").addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  document.getElementById("displayElem").style.visibility = "visible";
});

document.getElementById("hoverElem").addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  document.getElementById("displayElem").style.visibility = "hidden";
});
```

```css
#hoverElem {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  weidth: 200px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
#displayElem {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  weidth: 20px;
  top: 150px;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="hoverElem">
  A little Div
  <div id="displayElem">
    Tooltip to show
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("hoverElem").addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("displayElem").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }, 1000);
});`

Comment: Please refer this link. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131894/jquery-tooltip-set-timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131894/jquery-tooltip-set-timeout)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/milademobu/edit?html,css,output

why do you need js to make a tooltip? is there any strict requirement to do that with js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can intiate a timer in the `mouseleave` and then clear it in `mouseenter` of 
`displayElem` like

```js
document.getElementById("hoverElem").addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
  document.getElementById("displayElem").style.visibility = "visible";
});

var hoverTimer;
document.getElementById("hoverElem").addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  hoverTimer = setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("displayElem").style.visibility = "hidden";
  }, 500);
});
document.getElementById("displayElem").addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
  clearTimeout(hoverTimer);
});

document.getElementById("displayElem").addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
  this.style.visibility = "hidden";
});
```

```css
#hoverElem {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  weidth: 200px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: white;
}
#displayElem {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  weidth: 20px;
  top: 150px;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="hoverElem">
  A little Div
  <div id="displayElem">
    Tooltip to show
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

have you considered using pure CSS instead?

```css
div {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: black;
}

div:hover span,
span:hover{
  opacity:1;
}

span {
  display:block;
  opacity:0;
  color:orange;
  -webkit-transition-delay: .5s;
  transition-delay: .5s;
  -webkit-transition:opacity 1s ;
  transition:opacity 1s ;
    
  
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 150px;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: yellow;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>lorem Ipsum</span>
</div>
```